# Handling moment when async CoreDispatcher work completed or cancelled

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, async-await, winrt-async

For example, I need to use CoreDispatcher for refreshing MVVM properties in the UI Thread.

```
private void ButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //Code not compile without keyword async
    var dispatcherResult = this.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, async () =>
            {
                //This method contains awaitable code
                await _scanner.ScanAsync();
            }
            );

    dispatcherResult.Completed = new AsyncActionCompletedHandler(TaskInitializationCompleted);
} 

private void TaskInitializationCompleted (IAsyncAction action, AsyncStatus status )
{
    //Do something...
}
```

I am expect, then *TaskInitializationCompleted* handler will fire AFTER *ScanAsync* method completed, but it fire immediatly after *Dispatcher.RunAsync* method started and also BEFORE then *ScanAsync* was completed.

How I can check to really handle async Dispatcher work completed or cancelled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of registering to the `Completed` event, you can `await RunAsync` (Because `DispatcherOperation` is an awaitable) which will guarantee any code runs only after completion the invocations completion:

```
private async void ButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var dispatcherResult = await this.Dispatcher
                                .RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal,
                                 async () =>
            {
                await _scanner.ScanAsync();
            });

    // Do something after `RunAsync` completed
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It is good approach, but how to detect cancellation of operation, without workaround? May be to use standart approaches, with special handlers aka "Completed"?

Comment: @BorisSalimov What do you mean by cancellation? I don't see any cancellation mechanism in your code?

Comment: I mean, for example, if user clicked Back button. What is the best practice to handle this situation? Sorry, if my question is seems odd.

Comment: The best way would be to pass a `CancellationToken` to the `ScanAsync` method, which would monitor it in case someone from the outside cancelled it.

Comment: As I think you won't be able to get result from *RunAsync* as it's *IAsyncAction*. AFAIK it also won't work, hence as soon as code inside *RunAsync* hits await keyword it returns and begins `Do something ...` event the `ScanAsync()` is not yet completed. Maybe *TaskCompletitionSource* or other method would be better?